# How to export and import types in typescript?

Tags: typescript, vuejs3, nuxt3

I'm new to typescript
I have defined a type in an external file with Typescript.

WEbCam.ts

```
type  webCam = {
    id:string;
    status: string;
    title:  string;
    location : {
        latitude: number;
        longitude: number;
    }
    player : {
        day:{
            available:string;
            link:string;
        }
    } 
    image : {
            current : {
            thumbnail:string;
        }
    };
};

export {webCam};
```

Also, I imported the definition created as follows.

index.vue

```
import type { webCam } from "./webCam"
```

I got Error when build it.

```
Cannot overwrite a zero-length range – use appendLeft or prependRight instead
```

No error occurs if I write the  webCam type in index.vue.
What am I doing wrong?
and how to write the type to external file?

Comment: What happens when you use `import` instead of `import type`? The latter is a specialized form to allow fine grain control for advanced optimization and decoupling. It's not something you should reach for out of the box.